# SVG - Export of Points / Coordinates in Python

Tags: python, svg, coordinates, robotics, cnc

I am developing a robotic controlled drawing system and currently are looking for some input regarding the extraction of plain coordinates out of exisitng SVG-files. My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557673/python-get-coordinates-of-the-vector-path-from-svg-file), which did not get much feedback so far.

-> Is there some simple/established/prebuild way to extract point-coordinates out of existing SVG files within python ?

From my (limited) understanding, existing SVG libraries for python like [svg.path](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svg.path) and [pysvg](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysvg/0.2.2) do not seem to include a function for extracting all points out of an existing file (as they seem to be build more towards writing SVG rather than reading SVG..)

thanks for answers.

Comment: SVG is XML, use an XML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it made me rethink my question.
I understand that SVG is basically XML.


What I would like to avoid having to code myself (as I am far from being a professional programmer) is:

1) some function to get ALL Point Coordinates out of my SVG file aoutmatically in one simple list of X/Y coordinates


2) functionality to approximate line points of round shapes (like circles, ellipses and beziers which are defined by radius etc.)

Comment: Probably not the best site for you then, since this is for programming questions.